# Pass a router from root to component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is the way in which I am passing the router from my root to the component.

But the component is not called,

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/path" component={App}>
    </Route>
</Router>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Before the introduction of Router, this is how i was passing the component from root :

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root');
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Yo should implement your router in your App component

Comment: Isn't your App component the main one? If so the path should be "/".

Comment: this worked:  ```<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/path" component={Component} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,```